# Extract number from image that is well formatted using tesseract

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I have the following number:

[image]

I am using tesseract as documented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276602/python-pil-to-extract-number-from-image) question.

The result I am getting is "\n", and not 7000 as expected.

Has anyone experienced this issue in the past when trying to parse a number?

I have tried the following:

```
>>> image = Image.open("C:/temp/download.png")
>>> image = image.convert('RGB')
>>> image = image.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
>>> print image_to_string(image)


>>>image.save("C:/temp/dl1.png")
```

Which gives me

[image]

---

A step in the right direction is the following:

```
from PIL import ImageFilter
import sys
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ImageOps    
import pytesseract
import time


image=Image.open("C:/temp/download.png")
image.load() 
background = Image.new("RGB", image.size, (255, 255, 255))
background.paste(image, mask=image.split()[3]) # 3 is the alpha channel
background.save('C:/temp/foo.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=80)


img =Image.open('C:/temp/foo.jpg')
img.load()
print img
print '-------------------'
i = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print i
```

But now I am [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225927/pytesseract-cannot-find-the-file-specified).

Comment: Maybe try to preprocess the image, by for e.g. blurring?

Comment: @Ryan what would be the goal of blurring it?

Comment: to smoothen the image. The edges of the image in your question look 'pixely' and this may affect ocr performance. http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html

Comment: @Ryan see comments above.

Answer (score 0):

```
tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract'
```

In pytesseract.py change the tesseract_cmd to above line or path to where tesseract.It will work fine.