# pytesseract cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

My code is straight forward and is the following:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('C:/temp/foo.jpg')
img.load()
i = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

and the error response I get back is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "img.py", line 6, in <module>
    i = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 161, in image_to
_string
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesse
ract
  File "C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py",
line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py",
line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Any guidance would be fantastic.

Adding tesseract to my path variable helped:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR`

But the code now crashes when trying to run the pytesseract piece.

Comment: You can try using this another library to use Tesseract in Python: [pyslibtesseract](https://github.com/brunomacabeusbr/pyslibtesseract). This library use another way to load image.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just hit the same error and decided to answer this question - it might help someone to save time...

First, make sure you have [installed/copied Tesseract-OCR executables](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/master/Installation.md).

Windows can't find the executable `tesseract` in the directories specified in your `PATH` environment variable. So either make sure that the directory containing `tesseract` is in your `PATH` variable or overwrite `tesseract_cmd` variable in your Python script like as following (put your PATH instead):

```
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'
```

Beside that make sure that `TESSDATA_PREFIX` **Windows** environment variable is set to the directory, containing `tessdata` directory. For example:

```
TESSDATA_PREFIX=C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR
```

if `tessdata` location is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata`

Comment: To comment as well, I encourage installing tesseract FIRST then trying the python part.

Comment: @jasonm, i've updated my answer. Actually i thought it's too obvious to mention it, but, hey, you are right - it might confuse some inexperienced users.

Comment: @Jamie Bull I followed your advice for the path but cannot find the tessdata line

Comment: I am not even finding a Tesseract-OCR folder. I have a `pytesseract` folder, but that's it.

Comment: @ProQ, you need [to install (copy) Tesseract-OCR binaries](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki) first ...