# No module named pytesseract error

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to use pytesseract for OCR, on a raspberry pi using Raspbian

I have read several questions on this topic, but can't find an answer that works, they usually say to install pytesseract with pip, and I did it.

my code is very simple:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.jpg')))
```

But it returns error message : *"ImportError: No module named 'pytesseract'* .

I have installed tesseracrt-ocr (the **whereis tesseract-ocr** command returns  */usr/share/tesseract-ocr*)

I have installed pytesseract with **pip install tesseract** (which returns *successfully installed Pillow-4.3.0 olefile-0.44 pytesseract-0.1.7* ... but the **whereis pytesseract** command does not return anything --> a problem?).

Do you have any idea of the problem I have ?

Comment: Are you using any virtual environment , because , once you have installed pytessract using command pip install pytesseract , import pytesseract should work  .

Comment: No, just rasbian on a raspberry

Comment: Finally, I had also other problems. I reinstalled raspbian and everything works. But thanks for your help

Comment: Added the  help as an answer to help other , U can accept if it helped

Comment: please check this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225927/pytesseract-cannot-find-the-file-specified

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See after installing pytesseract ,using

```
<cmd>C:\> pip install pytesseract
```

Try :

> > > import pytesseract

If above is not working then it has do something with the installation , 
Check if pytesseract folder is available under "\Python27\Lib\site-packages" ,

Try the above command from site packages, Hope this helps , 
Else there is something wrong with installation .

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your code

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
```

set your path where tesseract-ocr is installed and also add this path to your window environment variable.Also check this link [Tesseract installation](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) for complete installation of tesseract.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why this line solves the issue?

Comment: pytesseract does not work by only pip install. https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/    check this link for complete installation of tesseract.This line of code specify the path of tesseract ..if the path is not set it throws the error tesseract is not in the path.