# Error in pytesseract importing

Tags: python, python-3.5, pytesser

Getting following error in pytesseract importing.

Code:

```
from pytesseract import image_to_string
from PIL import Image

tessdata_dir_config='--tessdata-dir "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata"'
im = Image.open(r'E:\\mini project\\tally.jpg')
print(im)
#text = image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng')

print(image_to_string(im,lang='eng',config=tessdata_dir_config))



<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=500x703 at 0x1B0D1E13828>
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "E:\mini project\main.py", line 10, in 
>       print(image_to_string(im,lang='eng',config=tessdata_dir_config))
>     File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 136, in image_to_string
>       nice=nice)
>     File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 82, in run_tesseract
>       proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>     File "C:\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)
>     File "C:\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo)
>   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Looks like you're filesystem is missing the tesseract OCR binaries. Possible duplicate of [pytesseract cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225927/pytesseract-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pytesseract cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225927/pytesseract-cannot-find-the-file-specified)