# Tesseract SyntaxError:'Creating User Config File' Error

Tags: tesseract

I have recently installed the Tesseract module and found some tutorials, but there was not any solution on the internet which I comfronted. Here are the simple codes and the error:

```
from PIL import Image
from tesseract import image_to_string
a = Image.open('/Users/bob/Desktop/108.jpg')
b = image_to_string(a)
print(b)
```

Here is the error:

```
print 'Creating user config file: {}'.format(_config_file_usr)
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the image: [108.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0wrF.jpg)

Comment: Try changing `from tesseract import image_to_string` to  `from .tesseract import image_to_string` (with leading dot)

Comment: It did not work. Now it's giving this following error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/esat/Desktop/Noting/Program/Code/OCR.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .tesseract import image_to_string
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.tesseract'; '__main__' is not a package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `from tesseract import image_to_string`

Do `pip install pytesseract` and `import pytesseract`

Also, make sure you're assigning the .exe in your .py file like so:

`pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'`

[This answer goes into depth on how to do it correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35830452/4329778)

and your program will need to be reworked from:

```
a = Image.open('/Users/bob/Desktop/108.jpg')
b = image_to_string(a)`
```

to

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('/Users/bob/Desktop/108.jpg'))
```